# Using stdin more than one time

Tags: c, stdin

I would like to ask, if it is possible to use stdin ended with EOF more than one time. I have something like that:

```
int ColumnCounter = 0; 
int Space = 1;
long IterationCounter = 0;
do
{
    while ((Char = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
            if ((Char != ' ')  && (Space == 1))
                {
                    ColumnCounter++;
                    Space = 0;
                }
            else if (Char == ' ')
                {
                    Space = 1;
                }
            else if (Char == '\n' || Char == '\0')
                {
                    putchar('\n');
                    Space = 0;
                    ColumnCounter = 1;
                    continue;
                }
            if (ColumnCounter == NumberOfCol)
                {
                    putchar(Char);
                }
        }
    ColumnCounter = 0;
    Space = 1;
    IterationCounter = NumberOfCol++;
    IterationCounter++;}
while (IterationCounter < EndingNumberOfCol + 1);
```

Continue in commentar below.

Comment: What is the `...`. `while (repeat = 5)` should be `while (repeat != 5)` perhaps. A `for` loop might be better

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it. I have tried it also for for-loop but it also didn't work.

Comment: Continue from question abowe.
I have <table.txt added to stdin and I need print columns from this table. For example when I get arguments ./project cols 1 4 <table.txt
Program print colum 1, 2, 3 and 4 from table.

Comment: Please do not change the question as in future some of the answers does not make any sense. Instead start a new question and accept the answer for the previous one.

Comment: Ok Ed, I appologize. I didn't want to make lots of same topics...

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Just as you've been doing it *almost* correctly! Use the following code:

```
int repeat=0; // Don't forget to initialize repeat
int Znak;
do
{
    while ((Znak = getchar()) != EOF)
    {          ...         }
    repeat++; //repeat not reapeat here
}
while (repeat<5); //loop until repeat is less than 5
```

EDIT: I see you've edited your code.So,Simply implement the above logic into your program.